# Full Text Search Displaying wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, myisam

// Create Table

```
CREATE  TABLE `TEST_FULL_TEXT_SEARCH` 
(
    `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `TEST` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `FULL_TEXT` (`TEST` ASC) 
)
ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

// Insert Some Records

```
INSERT INTO `TEST_FULL_TEXT_SEARCH` 
SELECT 1, 'vikas kumar gupta' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'kratika gupta' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'kratika sharma' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'kratika vikas kumar gupta' UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'kratika shukla' UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'chetan kastwar' UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'kratika kastwar' ;
```

// Now comes to the select query

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_FULL_TEXT_SEARCH
WHERE MATCH(test) 
AGAINST('kratika' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION );
```

// Or

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_FULL_TEXT_SEARCH
WHERE MATCH(test) 
AGAINST('kratika' WITH QUERY EXPANSION);
```

// Output

```
1   vikas kumar gupta
4   kratika vikas kumar gupta
3   kratika sharma
5   kratika shukla
2   kratika gupta
```

1. Why it is not selecting '**kratika kastwar**' in the result set?
2. Why 'vikas kumar gupta' on first

// Now we search in Boolean Mode

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_FULL_TEXT_SEARCH
WHERE MATCH(test) 
AGAINST('kratika' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

// Output

```
2   kratika gupta
3   kratika sharma
4   kratika vikas kumar gupta
5   kratika shukla
7   kratika kastwar
```

1. Why '**kratika kastwar**' is there?

// Now we search without query expansion in boolean mode

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_FULL_TEXT_SEARCH
WHERE MATCH(test) 
AGAINST('kratika' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

// Output

```
No result found
```

Please clarify why its not selecting '**kratika kastwar**' in the list

// Edited

Why its displaying '**vikas kumar gupta**' `IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION`
or in `WITH QUERY EXPANSION` on first rank not **kratika** related results?

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
SELECT ID, TEST, MATCH(TEST) AGAINST('kratika' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE ) AS MT FROM TEST_FULL_TEXT_SEARCH 
WHERE MATCH(TEST) 
AGAINST('kratika' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE  );
```

Result set is empty because the word 'kratika' is present in at least 50% of the rows.

Please check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-natural-language.html, where mentioned:

> Such a technique works best with large collections (in fact, it was
>   carefully tuned this way). For very small tables, word distribution
>   does not adequately reflect their semantic value, and this model may
>   sometimes produce bizarre results.

And they have a few samples.

Comment: read that link where `SELECT * FROM articles
     WHERE MATCH (title,body)
     AGAINST ('database' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);` fetching two results while 'database' is not 50% of the row the same in my case for kratika